# add spring jar to class path

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a netbeans java console project which uses Spring 3.0 ( which is a bunch of jars instead of a single jar).

when i try to execute it from the command line i get

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: com.aosprojects.transportservice.runner.InitialRunner. Program will exit.
```

How to fix this?

I have tried using -cp to specify the folder with all the jars in it like

```
java -cp libs/spring/* -jar dist/XXXXX.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using maven to build your application, it runs in the netbeans IDE, but you'll need to define a plugin in your maven pom.xml in order to include all of the required .jars in your final .jar to make it executable.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>yourmainpackagename.YourMainClass</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

This approach uses the maven shade plugin. You could also be using the maven assembly plugin, be prepared to face nasty bugs though :p

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This tells you the right way to do it:

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/set-classpath-in-eclipse-and-netbeans.html

Right click on project, select properties, and follow instructions.  Add all the JARs you need.

If it's an executable JAR, you have to add all the dependencies properly into the manifest.  Google for instructions on how to do that and give it a go.

Comment: i have already done that but when i navigate to dist folder and try to run the jar it gives the listed exception

Comment: You try to run the JAR?  It's an executable JAR?

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling using Netbeans IDE (with proper build path) then build artifact (the jar) and the `lib/` would be in dist directory.

cd into the `${project-root}/dist` directory and then run :

```
java -jar XXXXX.jar
```

The dependency on the libraries must be already taken care of in `MANIFEST` by Netbeans.

PS: See the generated README in the dist directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's my directory structure:**

~/downloads/
|--libs
---|--spring
------|--org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M1.jar
------|--org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M1.jar
------|--The rest of the jars
|--Spring.java

**The source code for Spring.java:**

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
public class Spring{ public static void main(String... args){ ApplicationContext ac; System.out.println("Successfully declared reference of type ApplicationContext. Exiting...");}}
```

**Navigate to ~/Downloads/ and execute the following:**

```
javac -cp "libs/spring/*" Spring.java
jar cvfe Spring.jar Spring Spring.class
java -cp ".:libs/spring/*" -jar Spring.jar
```

**Output:**

```
Successfully declared reference of type ApplicationContext. Exiting...
```